# Блок catch не выполняется

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Выполняю удаленную отладку сайта, который находится на веб-сервере IIS.

Внутри блока try генерируется исключение.Оператор catch "ловит" это исключение, однако код внутри блока catch не выполняется.В чем может быть причина?

Код на скриншотах выполняется последовательно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: переменная `emsg` где-то используется?

Comment: @Igor Для получения названия исключения. Просто, при удаленной отладке не удается поставить брекпоинт на фигурную скобку

Comment: значение, присвоенное переменной `emsg`, где-то используется?

Comment: @Igor нет, не используется

Comment: оптимизатор выкинул эту строчку

Comment: и что в целом за бесполезный код, выбросили исключение и сразу же отловили. удалите его вообще.

Comment: @teran Я указал простой пример, чтобы не было ответов типа "В коде не генерируется исключение"